# External Link cake php

Tags: cakephp, hyperlink, cakephp-2.0

my doubt is this, I have in a database table my news with my field 'link' and you can add a link in any table, except that when I go to the view and dolphins do not get me the link it redirects the q link I put it so does lotuscap.com / cakephpus / news / index / globo.com, I want to get only "globo.com" how do? It's route?

Sorry my english, thanks

Comment: It's very difficult to interpret your question. Perhaps pasting some code or using a [translator](http://translate.google.com) would help us understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to get the parameters using `$this->request->params['pass']`

[This link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passed-arguments) will help you to achieve the same as you asked.